# Get Timestamp from String and than a Date

Tags: java, sql, date, timestamp, sax

I am doing some XML parsing with SAX
Some elements look like this:

```
<show time="2014-07-05 20:00:00" />
```

I need to get a Timestamp out of above String.
Furthermore I also need to get a java.sql.Date, which of course should ignore the exact time.

I saw that there is a `Timestamp.parse(String s)` method available, but it is deprecated.

Therefore I wanted to ask what is the best Method to get a Timestamp out of this string, and a sql Date out of the Timestamp or String.

Thanks in advance

Edit:
I by the way still have to use Java 1.7 for this project

Comment: What Java version you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
java.text.SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
java.util.Date date = dateFormat.parse("2014-07-05 20:00:00");
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```